# How to insert Blade code in a React component inside a Blade view?

Tags: php, html, reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade

So I have a Laravel view called `homepage.blade.php`, it contains the following:

```
<body>
   <div id=root></div>
   <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Inside `app.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp";

if (document.getElementById("root")) {
    ReactDOM.render(<SignUp />, document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

and inside `SignUp.js`:

```
import React from "react";
export default function SignUp() {
    return (
<span className="text-xs font-bold uppercase"> Welcome, {!! auth()-> user() -> name !!} </span>
}
```

The `homepage.blade.php` is called by a function in a controller, like this:

```
//inside the function in the Controller.php:
$user = User::create($attributes);
auth()->login($user);
return redirect('/homepage');    // homepage redirects to homepage.blade.php
```

**The problem**: I can't insert the line `{!! auth()-> user() -> name !!}` inside the React component `SignUp.js` that will be inserted into the `homepage.blade.php` view.

**Question**: Is there a way to insert Blade code in a React component? and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use blade in js files. the proper way is, to define variable in blade file using `<script></script>` tag like this:

```
<script>
   const window.username = '{!! auth()-> user() -> name !!}';
   <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</script>
```

and then use the defined variable in your app.js file

Comment: app.js doesn't actually contain the JSX where I need to place the variable, it just checks if the the view that called it contains a div with id="root", if yes, then it renders the actual React component that contains the JSX in place of the div with the id "root" (check back the post please). Is there a way to pass this variable from app.js to SignUp.js (which is the React component containing the JSX where I should place the variable) ?

Comment: I don't have much react knowledge but the variable defined in blade file is a global variable and i thin you have access to it in the SignUp.js file. according to this link you can do it [link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-a-globally-defined-script-inside-a-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this. Blade only works on a script which is on MIME-type PHP. You have to load your JS file with .php so that your script can be rendered. Here is how you can do that:

1. Set header to let the caller know that it is a JS file.
2. Set your blade code inside the js. And change the file extension in PHP.
3. Put the JS file in your view(of your MVC) rename it to .php and put a header on your controller.
   This should work.